# Disable vertical scroll bar for md-autocomplete autosuggestion drop down

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

i want to disable scroll bar for md-autocomplete autosuggestion drop down.Is there any css or attribute way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to disable the scroll bar itself or do you want to disable scrolling altogether?

Comment: i want to disable or hide complete vertical scrolling in autosuggestion dropdown.

Comment: @aks Were you able to remove the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.
overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: can you please suggest on which md autocomplete class we have to apply this property?

Answer (score 0):

I could disable the vertical scrollbar by adding a new class to global **styles.scss** :

```css
.mat-autocomplete-panel.max-height-panel {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

... and set it to the Material component using the **classList** directive :

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class="max-height-panel" classList="max-height-panel" panelWidth="300px">
```